# Getting "Error 403--Forbidden" while accessing ADF bookmarked URL

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Here am trying to work with an ADF application to suport bookmarking.

Following are the steps I did to create a sample application.

1. Created a bounded task-flow (user-details.xml), which has the "Method call" as default activity along with an another view activity(userData.jsff page).
2. This task-flow takes an input parameter "Id" to display user details. In the method call activity user data will be initialized using the given input parameter and then the data will be displayed using userData.jsff page.
3. Created a view activity (details.jspx page) in adfc-config.xml file.
4. Marked the "details.jspx" file as bookmark-able by changing "Bookmark property to true" and given a Bookmark URL Parameter "Name is Id and Value is #{pageFlowScope.user_id}".
5. Dropped the bounded task-flow user-details.xml as a region into the details.jspx file.
6. Now the user_id which is coming as URL Parameter will be passed to user-details.xml task-flows input parameter value.
7. Created users.jspx page which lists all the users as home page. In the users.jspx page we'll have a link to user details page with a parameter Id.

By running the application will get users page. When I click on the user details link in the users page, the app showing user details page as expected.

Now I bookmarked the user details page. If I open the bookmarked page in the same tab, it is working fine. But when I open this bookmark in a new tab getting the "Error 403--Forbidden" response.
Bookmarked URL: localhost:7101/BookmarkTestApp-ViewController-context-root/faces/user_details?id=123&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrLoop=4884151149818&_adf.ctrl-state=35yghmx4f_18
When I click the above bookmark in another tab the url is processing for few seconds ( 2 to 3 seconds) and converts to localhost:7101/BookmarkTestApp-ViewController-context-root/ and giving 403 response. At this time it is not touching my beans at all (verified this by running the server in debug mode).

Am I missing any thing here.

Thanks in advance.

-Gopal.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing this URL: localhost:7101/BookmarkTestApp-ViewController-context-root/faces/user_details?id=123
See more here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/passing_parameters_to_adf_appl